# uber_rides.errors.UberIllegalState: Bad Request. Missing state parameter

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to just retrieve all my receipts amount from my Uber account and dump into excel. 
I installed uber_riders and trying to do that. I have no intention of creating a website or any other business purpose. My mere purpose is just fetch trips bills and dump to excel sheet.

So in my code.

```
    from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant
auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
    "xxx",
    "partner.trips",
    "xxx",
    "http://localhost/redirect_uri"
)
print auth_flow
auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()
session = auth_flow.get_session("http://localhost/redirect_uri")
```

So what should i fill in the redirect_uri ? I believe i don't need it. Can someone help me on what to do with this. I currently get `uber_rides.errors.UberIllegalState: Bad Request. Missing state parameter.`

Comment: I think you're better bet is to use riders.uber.com. The receipt endpoint API you are trying to hit for your personal use is not designed for receipt aggregation. "request_receipt - This is only granted to apps that request Uber rides directly and show receipts as part of the trip lifecycle. We do not allow apps to aggregate receipt information. The receipt endpoint will only provide receipts for ride requests originating from your application. It is not currently possibly to receive receipt data for all trips."

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, after spending some time thinking, I found this solution:

Execute till this statement as it is:
    `auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()`

After executing this instruction copy the `auth_url` and paste it into a browser.
If everything is fine, you would get to your redirected link with two parameters, 'code' and 'state', now copy this complete url along with the parameters, and use it for the `get_session()`

```
session = auth_flow.get_session(<new_url_here>)
```